# Is it a Kernel or a ROM that provides power_supply battery files?

Tags: battery, custom-roms, charging, kernel, bugs

Long story short I was installing custom ROMs to my Android device and one thing that stays in place regardless of ROM I use is a wrong battery stats monitoring. The device always behaves like it's being charged, although it's not.

I've checked the `/sys/class/power_supply/battery` and voila - there's no `battery`, only `/sys/class/power_supply/usb`. According to [some docs I've found](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/power/batteryless) that will make the system think it's connected to an external power source.

The question is **what is responsible for creating this `battery` file - is it a kernel, or a ROM** (i.e. LineageOS, Resurrection Remix etc).

---

**[UPD:]** In the document I've provided they write about  `/sys/devices/power_supply`, not `/sys/class/`, although [here](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/health/implementation) the `/sys/class/power_supply/*/` is mentioned as a Kernel interface. Should I assume that it's a Kernel issue then?

It's interesting though, that the *stock ROM does show battery stats correctly*, although nothing was added to `/sys/class/` and TWRP recovery I'm using shows battery charge as -1%.

Comment: Did you check `ls -d /sys/devices/*/power_supply/battery` or `ls -d /sys/devices/*/*/power_supply/battery` or `ls /sys/class/power_supply/battery`? Both ROM and kernel are involved in hardware handling. There must be some binary blob in `/vendor` acting as HAL which interacts with kernel, which ultimately deals with hardware. Mostly custom ROMs keep on including the same blobs in their ROMs extracted by someone. Do you face same issue with your stock ROM?

Comment: @IrfanLatif I've updated the question. Will go and read 'em manuals a bit more, thanks for showing the direction. And no, stock ROM was fine.

Comment: So you have checked and there is no `/sys/class/power_supply/battery/status`? If it exists `cat` it.

Comment: Yeah, there's even no `/battery` there - just `/usb`.

Comment: And there is no `pgrep -a hardware.health` either?

Comment: Nope =) I've decided to install stock ROM and then check what does it look like from the console. Will be back as soon as there'll be anything interesting to share.